# Is it possible to use the R function readline without requiring the user to press enter?

Tags: r, user-input

I am writing a small function that requires user input, which I have coded for using the `readline` function, but want to eliminate the need for the user to press [enter] after responding to the prompt in the console.

I have searched extensively on SO without finding a solution and the `readline` documention provides no potential solutions.

```
timer <- function() {
require(tictoc) #load required package

experiment_no <- readline("Experiment number: ")

while(T){       #open infinite while loop
    tic()       #start timer
    input_state=readline("State input: ")  #allow for entry of state
    if(input_state %in% 1:5){    #check if it's acceptable 
        elapsed=toc()            #if it is then end timer and record data
        write.table(cbind(experiment_no,input_state,elapsed$toc-elapsed$tic),'results.txt',col.names=F,row.names=F,quote=F,append=T)
    }else if(input_state=='t'){  #if input is 't' 
        break                    #break out of while loop
    }else if(input_state <1 | input_state > 5 & input_state!='t'){#if input is not and accepted state AND is not 't'
     print('thats not an allowed state- please try another')
     } 
 }
}
```

I would like the user to be able to input the experiment number into the console without pushing enter.

Comment: As someone who is prone to make typos I'd hate that ...

Comment: Try grabbing the input and setting it to some `TRUE` value that then forces printing. Can't test.

Comment: I don't think you can do that strictly on the console (I too have looked). However, if you don't mind using a graphics device, you can do something like `plot(NA); getGraphicsEvent(onKeybd=identity)` which will return a single-letter keypress when the graphic window is focused. Not ideal, I admit. (I have not tested this in the RStudio IDE, and it certainly won't work in a remote environment such as rstudio-server.)

Comment: @Roland, it's a cross between "touch-type training" and the "missile-command game from the James Bond movie *Never Say Never Again* that [delivers electric shocks to the loser](http://www.criticalcommons.org/Members/ccManager/clips/FF_Bond_Octopussy_VideogameH264.mp4/view)".

Comment: @Roland, I agree that it might not be ideal for everyone but this is for a personal package to streamline my work so am willing to live with the typos haha!

Comment: @r2evans, I am not sure how I would implement this into my code

Comment: @NelsonGon, I am not clear what you mean, sorry!

Comment: ColdWarKid, it can be used as a hackish replacement for `readline(...)`. Again, if you're willing to have a plot (whether meaningful or not) as the primary focus, then you can get each keypress individually.

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion and it doesn't appear to work with RStudiom, but many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57046151/10167927)' response, this solution only works in RStudio. It relies on the [rstudioapi](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi) package's ability to capture the input currently in the console.

```
dynamic_readline <- function() {
  while (rstudioapi::isAvailable()) {
    input <- rstudioapi::getConsoleEditorContext()$contents

    if (input != "") {
      rstudioapi::sendToConsole("", execute = FALSE)
      return(input)
    }

    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  }

  readline()
}
```

The `while` loop checks the content of the console every 0.1 seconds and returns the input if anything is entered. If something is detected, it sends `""` to the console to clear it. If rstudioapi isn't available (i.e. the editor isn't Rstudio), the function falls back to `readline()`.

The sleep time can be adjusted based on the response time you need, although in the R console you're not going to be getting 60 Hz gameplay.

You can also adjust the `if` statement to test for specific valid inputs rather than any non-empty input by using `%in%` instead of `!=`. (Something like `if (input %in% c("w", "a", "s", "d", "quit"))`). This would make it feasible to use this method with known inputs longer than one character.

Comment: is it still possible to add a prompt in this function?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: up front, this also doesn't work with RStudio. Since I'm confident RStudio is really intercepting and controlling quite a lot of R, while it is possible that `C_menu` has some other method of control (e.g., `options`), I think it is more likely that RStudio is intercepting the keypresses (thereby *forcing* `<enter>`-use). With that, I suggest that this leans towards a bug/feature-request with RStudio.

---

If you look at the source for `utils::menu`, you'll see at the end that it does:

```r
repeat {
        ind <- .Call(C_menu, as.character(choices))
        if (ind <= nc) 
            return(ind)
        cat(gettext("Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit\n"))
    }
```

This suggests that the `C_menu` function (not exported) can be (ab)used to do what you want. I don't know the internal workings of the function, so some empirical takeaways/caveats:

- usually (but not always[1]), the first pass in the `repeat` loop requires an enter for any entry;
- after that first `<enter>`, it appears to be `<enter>`-less for single-digit integers, anything else supports some arbitrary length and requires an `<enter>`

```r
repeat {
  ret <- .Call(utils:::C_menu, letters)
  if (ret == 0L) break
  cat("    you entered ", ret, "\n")
}
# Selection: 345            # I typed "345<enter>"
#     you entered  345 
# Selection: 3              # just "3", no enter
#     you entered  3 
# Selection: 4
#     you entered  4 
# Selection: 5
#     you entered  5 
# Selection:                # just enter
#     you entered  27 
# Selection: C              # "C<enter>"
#     you entered  27 
# Selection: c              # "c<enter>"
#     you entered  3 
# Selection: abc            # "abc<enter>"
#     you entered  27 
# Selection: 0              # just "0", no enter, it quits
```

I'm inferring that `27` means I entered something not in the original choices (`letters`).

Not sure if you can adapt your process to this, as it seems to be restricted to single-digit numbers (once you get past the first entry). I have not found the source for it yet to see if there's a companion function with other arguments.

Notes:

1. I can *infrequently* get the code to handle the enter-less entry on the first go, not sure if it's a matter of my code-editing (emacs/ess) or something else. If so, it is likely a bug somewhere.